# Python-Sphinx: how to fill the keyword fields for qthelp builder

Tags: qt, python-sphinx, qthelp

I'm using Sphinx for generating the documentation of my application, to be viewed using the [QtHelpEngine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhelpengine.html). Hence I'm using the [qthelp](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/builders.html) builder.

I don't understand how to properly create the keyword section of the qhp file from the reStructuredText used as source.

By default sphinx create an empty tag:

```
<keywords>

</keywords>
```

and then the `linksForIdentifier()` and `linksForKeyword()` return an empty `QMap`.

Comment: I haven't used the `qthelp` builder, but I assume that "keywords" in QtHelpEngine are the same as "index entries" as documented under [Index-generating markup](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/misc.html#index-generating-markup) in Sphinx using reStructuredText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sphinx fills the keywords with the same content it uses in the index of the documentation project. You find an overview of how to create index-generating markup markup [here in the Sphinx documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/misc.html#index-generating-markup) ([Steve Piercy's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2214933/steve-piercy) assumption is correct).

For example, if we have a the file `this/is/an/example.rst`, which contains this Python domain directive:

```
.. py:function:: lorem(ispsum)

   Lorems the provided ipsum.
```

, our `keywords` tag in the `.qhp` file contains the following keyword:

```
<keyword name="lorem() (built-in function)" ref="this/is/an/example.html#lorem"/>
```

An example for an explicitly created index entry is:

```
.. index::
   single: lorem
```

, which creates the following keyword (let's again assume the file is `this/is/an/example.rst`):

```
<keyword name="lorem" ref="this/is/an/example.html#index-0"/>
```